# Avoid circular dependencies while reaching methods

Tags: c#

I have been trying to figure out this issue i am having with dependencies. I need to have references from class A to B but also B to A. Is this even possible? A holds declared types that i need to use in B and so i need access to both A to B and B to A.

Is there a way around this or any ideas? The types in A cant be moved and the methods in B cant be moved either. (else there would not be any issue).

GUI - Factory - XMLSerialize,   where Factory is A and XML is B

//Regards

Comment: What do you mean by 'hold declared types'? It is certainly possible to declare two classes with methods/properties/fields referencing each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. You can not have circular dependencies. The common solution to your problem is to abstract the shared features into a third class and then reference that from A and B. If as you say this is not possible then perhaps your goal is not possible.

Comment: That's true for assemblies, but not classes.

Comment: @nunzabar - Circular references, yes ok, no problem. Circular Dependencies (i.e. inheritance), never (classes or assemblies).

Answer (score 2):

This not only sounds possible, it sounds normal.  For instance, a `Person` class could have a reference to a `Department` class and the `Department` could have a reference to a `Person`. You'll find examples of this all over the place.

Just try to avoid making a `Person` instance variable (property) in `Department`. You want to keep the references as short-lived as possible to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

This code has circular references and will compile just fine:

```
public class A {
    B b;
}

public class B {
    A a;
}
```

So I'm not sure what exactly is causing you issues. Perhaps you're trying to have A and B each as different assemblies (aka different dlls)? That would not be possible, unfortunately.

If you're in that sort of situation, then the best you can do is this:

Assembly 1:

```
public interface IA { ... }
public interface IB { ... }
```

Assembly 2 (depends on 1):

```
public class A {
  IB b;
}
```

Assembly 3 (depends on 2):

```
public class B {
  IA a;
}
```

Assembly 4 (depends on 1-3):

```
B b = new B();
A a = new A();
b.a = a;
a.b = b;
```

Comment: Yes, I will have to do it this way.Thanks alot for the help!!